# Weird bug in Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

In my application, I have my re-implemented `QGraphicsView` checking for a `mouseReleaseEvent()`, and then telling the item at the position the mouse is at to handle the event.

The `QGraphicsItem` for my view is made up of two other `QGraphicsItems`, and I check which one of the two is being clicked on (or rather having the button released on), and handle the respective events.

In my Widget's constructor, I set one of the items as selected by default, using the same methods I used when the items detect a release.

When I debugged, I found that for the `LabelItem`, select is called without a problem from the constructor (and the result is clear when I first start the application). But, when I click on the items, the application terminates. I saw that I was getting into the select function, but not leaving it. So the problem is here.

Which is very weird, because the select function is just a single line setter.

```
void LabelItem::select()
{
    selected = true;
}
```

This is the `mouseReleaseEvent`;

```
void LayerView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    LayerItem *l;

    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {           
        l = (LayerItem *) itemAt(event->pos());

        if(l->inLabel(event->pos()))     
        {                                 //No problem upto this point, if label is clicked on
            l->setSelection(true);        //in setSelection, I call select() or unselect() of LabelItem, 
                                          //which is a child of LayerItem, and the problem is there.
                                          //In the constructor for my main widget, I use setSelection
                                          //for the bottom most LayerItem, and have no issues.
            emit selected(l->getId());
        }
            else if(l->inCheckBox(event->pos()))
        {
            bool t = l->toggleCheckState();
            emit toggled(l->getId(), t);
        }
   }
}
```

When I commented the line out in the function, I had no errors. I have not debugged for the other `QGraphicsItem`, CheckBoxItem, but the application terminates for its events as well. I think the problem might be related, so I'm concentrating on `select`, for now.

I have absolutely no clue as to what could have caused this and why this is happening. From my past experience, I'm pretty sure it's something simple which I'm stupidly not thinking of, but I can't figure out what.

Help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code of the `mouseReleaseEvent()` function ?

Comment: This behavior will make sence, if you trying to dereference null or invalid `this` pointer. I mean, you may call `select` on null or invalid object and you dereference `this` in assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `LabelItem` is on top of the `LayerItem`, `itemAt` will most likely return the `LabelItem` because it is the topmost item under the mouse. Unless the `LabelItem` is set to not accept any mouse button with `l->setAcceptedMouseButtons(0)`.

Try to use [`qgraphicsitem_cast`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#qgraphicsitem_cast) to test the type of the item. Each derived class must redefine [`QGraphicsItem::type()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#type) to return a distinct value for the cast function to be able to identify the type.

You also could handle the clicks in the items themselves by redefining their [`QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#mouseReleaseEvent) method, it would remove the need for the evil cast, but you have to remove the function `LayerView::mouseReleaseEvent()` or at least recall the base class implementation, `QGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent()`, to allow the item(s) to receive the event.

Comment: It worked! I lacked understanding of how `QGraphicsView` interacts with its `QGraphicsItem`, and simply assumed I would get the item I had added, `LayerItem`. But the item I was getting was actually `LabelItem`. Goes to show I should read the documentation more thoroughly. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen these odd behaviours: It was mostly binary incompatibility - the c++ side looks correct, and the crash just does not make sense. As you stated: In your code the "selected" variable cannot be the cause. Do you might have changed the declaration and forgot the recompile all linked objects. Just clean and recompile all object files. Worked for me in 99% of the cases.

Comment: I did a complete rebuild, from the scratch with my source, and the same problem occurs. I'll post the code requested in the comments on my question, and see if anyone can make any sense of the bug.